Debug error when using CMake to build a Qt Widgets project
I wanted to develop my app using Qt and CMake in Visual Studio 2022. I installed everything and created a Qt Widgets App project.
Firstly, I created the project, used CMake build system for Qt, and set Qt version to 6.7.0_msvc2019_64.
While running, I had troubles with some DLLs — Qt6Cored, Qt6Guid, and Qt6Widgets missing in .exe's folder — so I copied them from Qt/6.7.0/msvc2019_64/bin. Now I have this error:

Debug Error!
Program: ...source\repos\Fasta-Reader\out\build\Fasta-
Reader\QT6Cored.dll
Module: 6.7.0
File:
C:\Users\qt\work\qtbase\src\gui\kernel\qguiapplication.cpp
Line: 1285
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

The file's path even doesn't exist on my computer — Qt is installed in C:/Qt, not in C:/Users.
If instead of CMake build system, I choose Qt Visual Studio Project, everything works correctly, but I need a CMake project.
My CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(FastaReader LANGUAGES CXX)

include(qt.cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}
    COMPONENTS
        Core
        Gui
        Widgets
)
qt_standard_project_setup()

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
    main.cpp
    FastaReader.ui
    FastaReader.h
    FastaReader.cpp
)

qt_add_executable(FastaReader ${PROJECT_SOURCES})

set_target_properties(FastaReader
    PROPERTIES
        WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(FastaReader
    PUBLIC
        Qt::Core
        Qt::Gui
        Qt::Widgets
)


Please, add to the question post textual representation of the error: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors
